# How do I place a space between these CSS circles?

Tags: html, css

I am currently trying to render various circles on a page. I am currently drawing the circles using modified CSS from the following web page:

https://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/

The CSS for circles in the link above draws the circles, but I am running into a couple of problems:

1. I need the circles to be spaced apart from one another (maybe `3px`?)
2. I need the circles to be in the same horizontal line
3. I can't seem to do 1 and 2 at the same time

I am using the following HTML and CSS:

```css
.circle-blue {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: deepskyblue;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.circle-gray {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: gray;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-blue cell"></div>
<div class="circle-gray cell"></div>
<div class="circle-blue cell"></div>
```

My circle `div`s in my HTML implement the `circle` and the `cell` classes.

The Plunker link below will lead you to my example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/SPHmKyOjF6GbTtjEFPrd?p=preview

NOTE: The circles are small, so you have to look at the very top left corner of the Plunker preview mode to find them.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that you are setting the `div` to `display: table-cell;`. `margin` does not apply to elements when their `display` property is set to `table-cell`. http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties states that `margin`:

> Applies to: all elements except elements with table display types other than table-caption, table and inline-table

One way to get the desired result would be to remove `display: table-cell;` and add `float: left;` and `margin-right: 3px;` to the circles instead.

```css
.circle-blue {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: deepskyblue;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.circle-gray {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: gray;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.cell {
  /*display:table-cell; Remove this*/
  font-size: 6px;
  float: left; /*Add this*/
  margin-right: 3px; /*Add this*/
}
```

```html
<div class="circle-blue cell"></div>
<div class="circle-gray cell"></div>
<div class="circle-blue cell"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you.  That worked.  As soon as SO's 9 minute policy for accepting an answer expires, I will select this one as the correct answer.

Comment: if you want to keep fluidity that you get from using table like for responsive then this technique wont work also float takes them out of regular flow and will not push your container down.

Comment: @idungotnosn No problem, glad I could help. I've added a little more detail to explain why `margin` was not working in your original example.

Comment: @DCdaz I think you are making this a bit more complicated that is necessary. Responsiveness is not a factor (it is not mentioned in the question) and all the answers address the core issues idungotnosn was facing. Having to clear floated content is hardly an issue either. ;)

Comment: @Hidden Hobbes display inline-block would have been a better alternative to float as floats are just ewww lol. what ever works for the quizzer i suppose.

Comment: @DCdaz Not sure why you think `float`s are _ewww_ as they are a perfectly valid way of laying out content. What method is most suitable all depends on the context in which it is being used. I would argue that using `float` is a neater way of laying out this content than forcing a `div` to act like a `table-cell`. But hey, both methods work at the end of the day. :)

Comment: @Hidden Hobbes they are stinky oh so very stinky lol. and yeah it totally depends on content id only ever use a float in conjunction with text for image layouts and wrapping. I just built on the question have to assume they are using table for a reason. plus I've got time to waste today. so might as well express my dislike of float's lol

Answer (score 3):

Use this

```
  .cell{
  margin-left: 5px;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 6px;
  }
```

Instead of

```
.cell{
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 6px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

when using table don't put content in them like images etc like that put a new div inside the cell specifically for content then use padding on your cell's to give spacing like below.

this way you get to keep cell's fluidity when doing responsive deign and it wont push down like float or inline-block would which I'm assuming you are doing since your using table for display.

---

```css
.circle-blue {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: deepskyblue;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.circle-gray {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: gray;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 6px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="cell">
  <div class="circle-blue"></div>
</div>
<div class="cell">
  <div class="circle-gray"></div>
</div>
<div class="cell">
  <div class="circle-blue"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

add this to the class 'cell'.

```
display: inline-block;
margin: 0 3px;
vertical-align: top;
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Xvoxb6fG3Mx2NAcRtD14?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

I think if you change `display: table-cell` to `inline-block`, you will get your expected result. of course you need margin too.
Hope this help !

Answer (score 0):

Would this be a viable solution?

https://hdcs.cz/?q=node/26

The code:

```
<style>
.circle-blue {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: deepskyblue;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.circle-gray {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  background: gray;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.cell {
  display: table-cell;
  font-size: 6px;
}
</style>
<table>
<tr>
<td style="padding: 5px"><div class="circle-blue cell"></div></td>
<td style="padding: 5px"><div class="circle-gray cell"></div></td>
<td style="padding: 5px"><div class="circle-blue cell"></div></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Regards,

Tomas Tudja